# Flatten tuple of bags and tuples

Tags: apache-pig, udf

I have a complex tuple with bags and tuples. How do I flatten it and access the bags?

I tried this code:

```
X = ({(a,b)},{(c,d),(e,f)},({(c,d),(e,f)},{g}),({(c,d),(e,f)},{h}))
Y = FOREACH X flatten($0);
Y = FOEACH Y GENERATE Y.$0;
```

But this doesn't seem to return the first bag.

Is there a way to return the first bag without using a UDF?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Hope it helps someone

```
X = ({(a,b)},{(c,d),(e,f)},({(c,d),(e,f)},{g}),({(c,d),(e,f)},{h}))
Y = FOREACH X flatten($0) as (bag1:bag{},bag2:bag{},tuple1:tuple(),tuple2:tuple());
Y = FOEACH Y  GENERATE bag1;
```